# problem with drupal when I change some configuration

Tags: php, drupal, hosting

I am a drupal newbie.
Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of such warning.

warning: Parameter 1 to profile_load_profile() expected to be a reference, value given in /data/multiserv/users/395147/projects/730411/www/includes/module.inc on line 462.

The line on question contains :

**
 * Invoke a hook in a particular module.
 *
 * @param $module
 *   The name of the module (without the .module extension).
 * @param $hook
 *   The name of the hook to invoke.
 * @param ...
 *   Arguments to pass to the hook implementation.
 * @return
 *   The return value of the hook implementation.
 */

function module_invoke() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $module = $args[0];
  $hook = $args[1];
  unset($args[0], $args[1]);
  $function = $module .'_'. $hook;
  **if (module_hook($module, $hook)) {** // this is line number 462
    return call_user_func_array($function, $args);
  }
}

and in file ../modules/profile/profile.module the function :

function profile_load_profile(&$user) {
  $result = db_query('SELECT f.name, f.type, v.value FROM {profile_fields} f INNER JOIN   {profile_values} v ON f.fid = v.fid WHERE uid = %d', $user->uid);
  while ($field = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    if (empty($user->{$field->name})) {
      $user->{$field->name} = _profile_field_serialize($field->type) ?   unserialize($field->value) : $field->value;
    }
  }
}

Comment: If you post the line in question and the first 10 lines before and after it, more people may be going to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a PHP 5.3 incompatibility issue, which should be fixed in the next minor release of Drupal 6:

http://drupal.org/node/360605